# Wildfly 10 Failed instantiate InitialContextFactory com.sun.jndi.LDAPCtxFactory from classloader ModuleClassLoader

Tags: jboss, wildfly

I have an ear with an ejb that I've deployed in Wildfly 10 the ejb is trying to make an initialcontext to ldap but I get the error above. I'm new to JBOSS/Wildfly and i'm trying to port code from weblogic.

Failed instantiate InitialContextFactory com.sun.jndi.LDAPCtxFactory from classloader ModuleClassLoader
Can anyone help

Comment: copy the stack trace

Comment: error when trying to create the contextWFLYNAM0027: Failed instantiate InitialContextFactory com.sun.jndi.LDAPCtxFactory from classloader ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.LM_Ver_3_1.ear.ejb_lm_lmLdap.jar:main" from Service Module Loader

Comment: This was caught as a NAMINGEXCEPTION

Answer (score 0):

Answer to my own question, initially i was looking for this com.ibm.jndi.LDAPCtxFactory and i hadn't used the modules correctly and then i tried com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory had typed in com.sun.jndi.LdapCtxFactory by mistake. Both were my fault. :(